# Add image at top of each D3 bar rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add an image in each bar rect of a D3 bar chart. So, as a start the rect will have a radius at the top rect edges and an image will float (at the top). After achieving this, I will try to have a different image for each bar rect (I will only have 3 bar rects in my cart). What I want to achieve is here:

[image]

My first attempt which doesn't work is here:

```js
  var data = [{"letter":"A","frequency":0.08167},{"letter":"B","frequency":0.01492},{"letter":"C","frequency":0.02782}];

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    x = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.1),
    y = d3.scaleLinear();

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x");

  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y");

  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Frequency");

  // DRAWING

  function draw() {

    var bounds = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect(),
      width = bounds.width - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = bounds.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    x.rangeRound([0, width]);
    y.rangeRound([height, 0]);

    g.select(".axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    g.select(".axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10, "%"));

    var bars = g.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(theData);

    // ENTER
    bars
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

    // UPDATE
    bars.attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.frequency); })
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.frequency); });

    // ADD IMAGE 
     bars.enter()
        .append('image')
        .attr({
          'xlink:href': 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/Z/w/n/R/W/red-smiley-face-hi.png',
          x: function (d) { return x(d.letter); },
          y: 0,
          width: x.bandwidth(),
          height: 28
        });


    bars.exit().remove();

  }

      theData = data;

      x.domain(theData.map(function (d) { return d.letter; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(theData, function (d) { return d.frequency; })]);

      draw();
  
  window.addEventListener("resize", draw);
```

```css
  .bar {
    fill: purple;
  }

  .bar:hover {
    fill: pink;
  }

  .axis--x path {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="300px"></svg>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

I then tried to see if the idea works in a different D3 bar chart (which I am not going to use as it is not responsive). The image shows normally but the y position must change. I will no further work on this snippet as I need to work on the first bar graph :

```js
var nutritionFields = ["calories", "protein", "sodium"];

var data = [
  {
    "cereal": "100%_Bran",
    "manufacturer": "Nabisco",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 70,
    "protein": 4,
    "fat": 1,
    "sodium": 130,
    "fiber": 10,
    "carbs": 5,
    "sugars": 6,
    "shelf": 3,
    "potassium": 280,
    "vitamins": 25,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": 0.33
  },
  {
    "cereal": "100%_Natural_Bran",
    "manufacturer": "Quaker Oats",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 120,
    "protein": 3,
    "fat": 5,
    "sodium": 15,
    "fiber": 2,
    "carbs": 8,
    "sugars": 8,
    "shelf": 3,
    "potassium": 135,
    "vitamins": 0,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": -1
  },
  {
    "cereal": "All-Bran",
    "manufacturer": "Kelloggs",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 70,
    "protein": 4,
    "fat": 1,
    "sodium": 260,
    "fiber": 9,
    "carbs": 7,
    "sugars": 5,
    "shelf": 3,
    "potassium": 320,
    "vitamins": 25,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": 0.33
  },
  {
    "cereal": "All-Bran_with_Extra_Fiber",
    "manufacturer": "Kelloggs",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 50,
    "protein": 4,
    "fat": 0,
    "sodium": 140,
    "fiber": 14,
    "carbs": 8,
    "sugars": 0,
    "shelf": 3,
    "potassium": 330,
    "vitamins": 25,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": 0.5
  },
  {
    "cereal": "Almond_Delight",
    "manufacturer": "Ralston Purina",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 110,
    "protein": 2,
    "fat": 2,
    "sodium": 200,
    "fiber": 1,
    "carbs": 14,
    "sugars": 8,
    "shelf": 3,
    "potassium": -1,
    "vitamins": 25,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": 0.75
  },
  {
    "cereal": "Apple_Cinnamon_Cheerios",
    "manufacturer": "General Mills",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 110,
    "protein": 2,
    "fat": 2,
    "sodium": 180,
    "fiber": 1.5,
    "carbs": 10.5,
    "sugars": 10,
    "shelf": 1,
    "potassium": 70,
    "vitamins": 25,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": 0.75
  },
  {
    "cereal": "Apple_Jacks",
    "manufacturer": "Kelloggs",
    "type": "C",
    "calories": 110,
    "protein": 2,
    "fat": 0,
    "sodium": 125,
    "fiber": 1,
    "carbs": 11,
    "sugars": 14,
    "shelf": 2,
    "potassium": 30,
    "vitamins": 25,
    "serving size weight": 1,
    "cups per serving": 1
  }
];

                var cerealMap = {};
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    var cereal = d.cereal;
                    cerealMap[cereal] = [];

                    // { cerealName: [ bar1Val, bar2Val, ... ] }
                    nutritionFields.forEach(function(field) {
                        cerealMap[cereal].push( +d[field] );
                    });
                });
                
      

            var makeVis = function(cerealMap) {
                // Define dimensions of vis
                var margin = { top: 30, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
                    width  = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
                    height = 250 - margin.top  - margin.bottom;

                // Make x scale
                var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(nutritionFields)
                    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

                // Make y scale, the domain will be defined on bar update
                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([height, 0]);

                // Create canvas
                var canvas = d3.select("#dropdown")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width","100%")
                .attr("height","100%")
                .attr("viewBox","0 0 "+
                    (width+margin.left+margin.right)+
                    " "+
                    (height+margin.top+margin.bottom) )
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform","translate("+
                    margin.left+","+margin.top+")");

                // Make x-axis and add to canvas
                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale)
                    .orient("bottom");

                canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

                // Make y-axis and add to canvas
                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient("left");

                var yAxisHandleForUpdate = canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y axis")
                    .call(yAxis);

                yAxisHandleForUpdate.append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", ".71em")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Value");

                var updateBars = function(data) {
                    // First update the y-axis domain to match data
                    yScale.domain( d3.extent(data) );
                    yAxisHandleForUpdate.call(yAxis);

                    var bars = canvas.selectAll(".bar").data(data);

                    // Add bars for new data
                    bars.enter()
                      .append("rect")
                        .attr("class", "bar")
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) { return xScale( nutritionFields[i] ); })
                        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
                        .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - yScale(d); });
          
                   bars.enter()
                     .append('svg:image')
                      .attr({
                        'xlink:href': 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/Z/w/n/R/W/red-smiley-face-hi.png',  // can also add svg file here
                        x: function(d,i) { return xScale( nutritionFields[i] ); },
                        y: 0,
                        width: xScale.rangeBand(),
                        height: 28
                      });
                   
                    // Update old ones, already have x / width from before
                    bars
                        .transition().duration(250)
                        .attr("y", function(d,i) { return yScale(d); })
                        .attr("height", function(d,i) { return height - yScale(d); });

                    // Remove old ones
                    bars.exit().remove();
                };

                // Get names of cereals, for dropdown
                var cereals = Object.keys(cerealMap).sort();

                var initialData = cerealMap[ cereals[0] ];
                updateBars(initialData);
            };
            
            makeVis(cerealMap);
```

```css
        select {
            display: block;
        }
        .bar {
            fill: purple;
            opacity: 0.8;
            border-radius:15px;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div id="dropdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, but you were setting the attributes on the image element in a nonstandard way.  Note I added the preserveAspectRatio = None and top = 1/2 height (-14px) so it would more closely match your sample image.  If you want the aspect ratio to match the width you need to calculate the height and also the top.  Also you'll need to extend the height by the 1/2 height of the tallest image so it wouldn't get cut off.

```
// ADD IMAGE 
 bars.enter()
    .append('image')
    .attr('xlink:href', 'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/P/Z/w/n/R/W/red-smiley-face-hi.png')
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", "28px")
    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.frequency) - 14; })
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.letter); })
    .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
```

Note the y attr is calculated.

Comment: That looks way better. It is not responsive on resize (checking why). If numbers are low, the image looks weird (Haven't though about this scenario yet).